# Xamarin.Forms get standard color of TextCell's label

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a custom ViewCell with a StackLayout like this:

```
var viewLayout = new StackLayout () {
            Padding = new Thickness (10, 0, 10, 0),
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = { nameLabel,  button1, button2 }
        };
```

When I use Xamarin.Forms standard ViewCells, i.e "TextCell", the label will get a blueish color on Android. My questions is: Where can I find this property?  I want to set it to my custom `nameLabel` like this:

```
nameLabel.TextColor = TextCell.StandardTextColorForCurrentPlatform;
```

Answer (score 0):

For TextCells:-

On **Android** you can get this value via **Color.Accent**.

On **WindowsPhone** use the system-defined **PhoneForegroundBrush**.

**iOS** appears to be hard coded to black.

You can write a simple **DependencyService** to return the appropriate color per the platform your executing on.